# Forwarding a request via middleware in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In other frameworks, the concept of request forwarding exists, were a request can be internally redirected to another controller action within the app without responding back to the user with an explicit redirect.

For an ecommerce example, if a product has a SEO-friendly URL of `/red-shoes.html`, a request to that URL would internally forward to `/catalog/product/id/1234`. The user would receive a 200 response code and the product page for product ID 1234 would be rendered at the original URL of `/red-shoes.html`. The behavior I'm trying to avoid is issuing a 301 redirect to `/catalog/product/view/id/1234` and losing the friendly URL.

How can this be accomplished in Laravel (5.7)? I can introduce a piece of middleware to intercept the request, but in middleware, I can only redirect within the app. `redirect()` sends a 302 back to the user, which I *don't* want.

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use App\Rewrite;

class ProductForward
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // make a lookup to see if URI in request matches a known product
        $productId = Product::lookupRequest($request);
        if ($productId) {  // if matches, forward to product controller
            return redirect()->route('catalog_product', ['id' => $productId]);  // not desired
        }
        // if no match is found, continue on with the request
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

As a follow-up, is it possible to execute this lookup after routing has completed, if no route matches?

For example, assume the route `/login` exists to render the login page. If the user goes to `/login`, there's no point in looking up a product-friendly URL for this request - just render the login page. But, if the user visits `/blue-shoe.html`, and that's not a pre-defined route in Laravel, execute the product lookup and forward *after* app routing but *before* a 404 is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could SEO-friendly URLs be in a section like `products/red-shoes`?

Then you can create a route with parameter like `Route::get('products/{seoName}');` that will lead to the same controller you use for handling requests like `/catalog/product/view/id/1234`. There you can resolve and find out that a controller's action was reached with product's ID or seo-name and show a matching product.

Basically, you can have two routes `products/red-shoes` and `/catalog/product/view/id/1234` that will show the same page, without redirect.

**Controller action**

Also, you can execute a controller method directly from the middleware.

Instead of calling

`return redirect()->route('catalog_product', ['id' => $productId]);`

you may run something like

`return app('App\Http\Controllers\ProductController')->show($productId);`

Then you will get a content of a product page without a redirect.

**Fallback route**

To prevent running the middleware on every request you can use a fallback route.

```
Route::fallback(function () {
    //
});
```

A fallback route will only be executed if a request does't match any of the registered routes. In such a scenario, you can search for a product, and if nothing is found, return a 404 response.

This could look like this:

```
Route::fallback(function ()
{
    // make a lookup to see if URI in request matches a known product
    $productId = Product::lookupRequest(request());
    if ($productId) {  // if matches, forward to product controller
        return app('App\Http\Controllers\ProductController')->show($productId);
    }
    abort(404);
}
```

A fallback route should be registered last in your file.

For more information, please refer to [Fallback Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#fallback-routes).

Comment: Unfortunately not. We're migrating from another system that has thousands of existing URLs that we need to maintain.

Comment: @ToddM, got it. You may try to use controller method from your middleware, check the update of the answer.

Comment: I _think_ that should work for the first part. Ideas about the follow up piece?

Comment: @ToddM you can use a fallback route. I updated the answer.